# Deploying Spring Boot Microservice to Kubernetes Issue - Failed to pull image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a problem about deploying all spring boot microservices to Kubernetes.

I use minikube to open kubernetes dashboard through all these commands shown below.

```
1 ) minikube start
2 ) minikube dashboard
```

Next, I run `kubectl apply -f k8s` to deploy all services to Kubernetes.

I get errors shown below.

```
Auth Service -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/authservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Api gateway -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/apigateway": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Config server -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/configserver": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Order Service -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/orderservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Payment Service -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/paymentservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Product Service -> Failed to pull image "noyandocker/productservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.2:53: read udp 192.168.49.2:59506->192.168.65.2:53: i/o timeout

Mysql -> Show always "Pending" -> The selected container has not logged any messages yet.

Eureka -> container "eureka" in pod "eureka-0" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

Here is the screenshot folder :[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nwPCDDIZ3_Go4YmJz5wG7rRF1pt7Bo4b?usp=share_link)

Here is the docker hub : [Link](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=noyandocker)

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

Here is the minikube running on docker.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix all these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

After I changed the line shown below, the issue disappeared.

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try from inside a clusternode if you can reach the internet. Ping google.com for example?

```
minikube ssh to access the minikube node.
```

Most likely it is network problem.

If so you need to specify a driver, according to your OS and Virtualizzation. (HyperV, VirtualBox ecc.)

You can found a complete list [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/)

Comment: I have no issue to run kubernetes dashboard. It works. My issue is different than you think. How can I fix it if you have any idea?

Comment: Its not about dashboard. Your kubernetes node is not able to pull the images. Check if your kubernetes node reach the internet from inside, as i wrote about. Would be good you tell what Host OS you have and if you installed a network driver with minikube.

Comment: When I run minibuke start command, it works and I can see it in Docker Desktop. There is no problem here.

Comment: You are not getting the problem. You must check the connetivity from inside the minikubes docker image. You are running kubernetes in a docker image. The pull that dont work is not a pull on your windows macchine, It is a pull inside the minikube kubernetes docker container itselfs. Again check the network from inside the the kubernetes node (the docker container you see)

Comment: I show its screenshot. As I mentioned before, it already worked.

Comment: You are still not getting it. You have a docker inside docker. In a Kubernetescluster (Minikube or what else) you have also docker running. Means inside that Container with minikbe there will run containers. Container inside a container. Check your network from inside the container. You cant pull images inside the minikube container if it cant reach the internet.

Comment: What should I write after minikube ssh? I write ping www.google.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251017/discussion-between-ralle-mc-black-and-qwercan).